# Jest, TypeScript: Missing semi colon error

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I am writing basic test using Jest for my angular project. However, I get a weird missing semi-colon error that I cannot understand how to fix.

```
import { RegistrationService } from "../registration/services/registration.service";
describe("Email Validator function", () => {
let registrationService: RegistrationService;

test("Check Email Exists", () => {
    const input = 'donotreply@example.com';

    expect(registrationService.checkIfEmailAvailability(input)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: src\app\__tests__\email-validator.spec.ts: Missing semicolon (4:25)

  2 |
  3 | describe("Email Validator function", () => {
> 4 |   let registrationService: RegistrationService;
```

Comment: Does Jest know it's dealing with TypeScript, not JavaScript? I mean, I see the file extension, but is the config set up to handle it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you help me understand how to ensure it is dealing with typescript? The filename extension is .ts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited my question, does that help?

Comment: @JasonChang - https://jestjs.io/blog/2019/01/25/jest-24-refreshing-polished-typescript-friendly#typescript-support

Comment: That's better, but it's not clear how you've configured Jest to run that. It seems to be interpreting your TS file as JS, assuming that `let name` will be followed by either `;` (initialise variable with undefined) or `=`, not `:`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring Jest for Typescript, es6 and Webpack 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080230/configuring-jest-for-typescript-es6-and-webpack-2)

Comment: That helped! I had to install ts-jest and add jest.config.js as described here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed instructions here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/jest

Basically I was missing ts-jest and the jest.config.js as mentioned in that article.

Comment: The `transform` key is what I was missing!